# Convert text framed with asterisks(**) to italic, using sed command in Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, sed

The requires are bellow:
Convert text framed with asterisks to italic. Don't touch text in double asterisks (bold). Use sed command.
For example,

```
*italic*  =>  <em>italic<\em>
**not italic**  =>  **not italic** (nothing change)
*text**text*   =>   <em>text**<\em>
```

Here is my command:

```
sed -n -r 's#(^|[^*])\*([^*]+)\*#\1<em>\2</\em>#gp' test.txt
```

It work for case 1 and 2, but facing case 3 it gives a wrong output:

```
<em>text <\em>* text*
```

How I suppose to make it work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `*not italic*` is a sub-string of `**not italic**`, therefore is should be italic, according to your rules.

I have tried to use the regexp `(\*((?!\*)(.+?))\*)` with the testing program check-regexp and it worked well, but the just mentioned problem is still present. See...

```
$ check-regexp '(\*((?!\*)(.+?))\*)' '****alpha**beta**gamma***'

searching      : ****alpha**beta**gamma***
for the regexp   : (\*((?!\*)(.+?))\*)
num of subexps   : 3
prefix: ***
what[0]: *alpha*
  what[1]: *alpha*
  length: 7
  what[2]: alpha
  length: 5
  what[3]: alpha
  length: 5
suffix: *beta**gamma***
what[0]: *beta*
  what[1]: *beta*
  length: 6
  what[2]: beta
  length: 4
  what[3]: beta
  length: 4
suffix: *gamma***
what[0]: *gamma*
  what[1]: *gamma*
  length: 7
  what[2]: gamma
  length: 5
  what[3]: gamma
  length: 5
suffix: **
total number of matches: 3


$ check-regexp '(\*((?!\*)(.+?))\*)' '****alpha**'

searching      : ****alpha**
for the regexp   : (\*((?!\*)(.+?))\*)
num of subexps   : 3
prefix: ***
what[0]: *alpha*
  what[1]: *alpha*
  length: 7
  what[2]: alpha
  length: 5
  what[3]: alpha
  length: 5
suffix: *
total number of matches: 1
```